# Java File Read in As Array

Tags: java, arrays

[I am really stuck here, I can't seem to read in the arrays properly.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C2lCi.png)

I can't seem to read in these arrays into columns. Looking for a solution to help me finally make an array out of these numbers.

```
public class TextFileInputAndOutput
{   
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("USStateCapitalsSelected.txt"));
    int lineCounter = 1;
    String line;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

        // parse line using any method.
        // example 1:

        Scanner intScanner = new Scanner(line);
        while (intScanner.hasNextLine()) {
            String nextInt = intScanner.nextLine();
            System.out.println(nextInt + "Herro");
            if (intScanner.hasNextDouble() == true) {
                Scanner scanner = new Scanner(line);
                while (scanner.hasNextDouble()) {
                    String nextString = scanner.next();
                    System.out.println(nextString);
                }
            }
        }


    }
  }
}
```

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: You should first have a look at `Scanner` that's what you need, then try some simple things like reading the first line of a file and see what happens. Then you show us the code that is actually reading the file - and possibly an  example of the content. FYI: you can paste the code here (formatted) instead of posting an image - makes it easier to read

Comment: Um. I am utilizing Scanner in my above program. And I am reading the first line of a file. The issue is breaking up the columns into arrays vertically based on the category.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **com.google.common.io.Files**:

Sample.txt:

> nameA labA quizeA
>       nameB labB quizeB

Code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    File myFile = new File("Sample.txt");

    ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> labs = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> quizes = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (String line : Files.readLines(myFile, Charset.defaultCharset())) {
        String[] cols = line.split(" ");
        names.add(cols[0]);
        labs.add(cols[1]);
        quizes.add(cols[2]);
    }

    System.out.println(names);
    System.out.println(labs);
    System.out.println(quizes);
}
```

Comment: Can you show me the content of USStateCapitalsSelected.txt?

Answer (score 0):

Tryb this

```
try{
    File file = new File("filename");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);
    while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = sc.nextLine();
        String[] temp = line.split(" ");

        //add values to arraylist
        names.add(temp[0]);
        labs.add(temp[1]);
        quizes.add(temp[2]);             
    }
    }catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```